# How do I install UHD in Precise?

Tags: 12.04, networking, package-management, kernel

I want to install UHD libraries.

I run

```
sudo apt-get install libuhd-dev libuhd003 uhd-host
```

but I get:

```
E:unable to locate packages ibuhd-dev
E:unable to locate packages libuhd003
E:unable to locate packages uhd-host
```

How do I install uhd?

Answer (score 0):

These packages appeared in Ubuntu repositories starting with Ubuntu 14.04 version.

You can't install them to 12.04 this way.

You can upgrade your system to 14.04 and install these packages.